# Why does Java have nested try statements?

Tags: java, try-catch

I read about nested `try`-`catch` statements and I can't help but wonder what is the actual point of using nested `try`? The contents of the inner `try` are already in the outer `try`, and if an exception is to be caught, the outer `try`-`catch` will handle it. So why use inner `try`?

For example:

**Code 1:**

```
try 
{
    Statement A;
    Statement B;
    try
    {
        Statement C;
        Statement D;
    }
    catch(CException e) { ... }
    catch(DException e) { ... }
}
catch(AException e) { ... }
catch(BException e) { ... }
```

**Code 2:**

```
try 
{
    Statement A;
    Statement B;

    Statement C;
    Statement D;
}
catch(AException e) { ... }
catch(BException e) { ... }
catch(CException e) { ... }
catch(DException e) { ... }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but don't these two code snippets above perform the same task?

Comment: No problem. Anyway, now I got the idea why do we use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a loop around the inner try, to catch exceptions multiple times without exiting the loop.

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            someOperationThatOftenFails();
        } catch (SomeCommonException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
} catch (SomeRareFatalException e) {
    ...
}
```

In this scenario, nested try blocks are the only way of catching `SomeCommonException` multiple times without exiting the loop, but also causing `SomeRareFatalException` to exit the loop the first time it occurs.

Comment: Thanks..this example explains the use of nested `try` beautifully :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes the code snippets you happened to give happen to behave identically.  Now consider

```
try 
{
    Statement A;
    Statement B;
    try
    {
        Statement C;
        Statement D;
    }
    catch(CException e) { ... }
    catch(DException e) { ... }

    Statement E;
    Statement F;
}
catch(AException e) { ... }
catch(BException e) { ... }
```

E and F are to be executed regardless of the outcome of C and D.  How are you going to do that with a single try ?  (Possible answer : duplicate the E/F code block in the pertinent catch blocks.  Not very elegant.)

The ***full*** semantics of an exception thrown are not only its type (/class) but also the spot in the code where it got thrown.  Scope matters.

Comment: yeah, I didn't thought of this case..no I get the whole point of nested try statements. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

If you catch the exception at the same level, you're not able to execute other instructions when the code throw the first one.

Not all exceptions are the same, you should treat each one in a specific manner.

Some just need to log that something happened, and then move on with the code.

Other time, you can't go on and have to stop.

The reason exceptions exists, is to be able to handle the errors on the proper level.

For example, you can put in the signature of your method that the code may throw exceptions, so the caller have to deal with such errors.

So it make sense to have nested *try catch* blocks according to the logic the code is implementing.

I could agree that you should avoid to write too much nested exception blocks.

The reason is that the code became difficult to understand.

But, to solve this issue, you should design your code better, instead of just use a single big *try catch*.

That approach is dangerous as to have the code difficolt to understand, because when an exception is thrown you will have hard time to figure out what really happened.

Instead, you should split up your code in more reasonable units designign small methods, small classes and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I get it :)